# Harmonic conjugate in a projective plane

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

In $\mathbb{P}_2(\mathbb{K})$ with $\mathbb{K}\ne\mathbb{Z}_2$,

Given $ABCD$ in a line with ordering 
$$A(1,0,0),~D(1,-1,0), ~B(0,1,0), ~C(1,1,0)$$ where $D$ is the harmonic conjugate of $C$ respect to $A$ and $B$

I was wondering why $D$ is the conjugate, I have tried the cross-ratio but cannot obtain that:
$$(A,B;C,D)=\frac{[AC][BD]}{[AD][BC]}=-1$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the following figure.

Points $A,B,C,D$ having their third coordinates $0$ are in fact points **at infinity** in the direction indicated by points

$$A_1(1,0,1), \  B_1(0,1,1), \ C_1(1,1,1), \ D_1(1,-1,1)$$

(same first two coordinates as $A,B,C,D$ but third projective coordinate equal to $1$).

You must know that points at infinity can be considered as straight lines, here $OA_1,OB_1,OC_1,OD_1$, constituting what is called a **pencil of lines**. What do we see ? That $OA$ and $OB$ are bissectors of $OC$ and $OD$.

This is enough: this situation is a characteristic property of harmonic conjugation for a pencil of lines.

But you may prefer a proof using cross ratio. There is a theorem saying that, whatever the pencil of lines, taking any sectional line intersecting the different lines of the pencil in, say $A',B',C',D'$, the value of cross ratio $[A',B';C',D']$ is the same whatever the sectional line (thus, it is called the "cross ratio of the pencil"). Let us take for example sectional line $(S)=C_1D_1$: it is clear that if we take on $(S)$, $A_1$ as the origin and $C_1$ as the point with abscissa 1, the abscissa of $D_1$ is $-1$ and the abscissa of the intersection of $OB_1$ with $(S)$ is point $B$ (at infinity). In such a situation the value of the cross ratio is $-1$ because $\dfrac{[A_1C_1]}{[A_1D_1]} \times\dfrac{[BD_1]}{[BC_1]}=-1 \times 1$ (intuitively: the second fraction is equal to 1 because $B$ is so "far away" that the distance $BD_1$ is the same as the distance $BD_1$).

[image]

Comment: I have modified the figure and the text.

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation ! would you mind explain more about $(-1,1;0,\infty)$ whose value is $-1$, i am not very familiar with the notations

Comment: I have explained a little more using a different sectional line.

Comment: And still a little more...

Comment: ahhh i think i got it ! thanks, but its kinda tricky to think about "intersection of $OB_1$ with $(S)$ is point $B$", this yields the latter fraction is 1, so perfect ! I appreciated u so much.

Comment: just suddenly think of a question: if I want to find the harmonic conjugate of the another point like $(1,k,0)$, here i assume its $x$ coordinate is $1$ just for simplicity, is it possible to find $y=-k$ by only considering the "bisector matter"? here i have assumed $(1,-k,0)$ is the only possibility for the conjugate

Comment: I answer now because I was away for a while. Yes, the "bissector manner" works but gives the result $(1,-1/k,0)$ because if a line passing through the origin has slope $k$, the line orthogonal to it passing through the origin has slope $-1/k$  (compare equations $y=kx$ and $y=(-1/k)x$).